# How to set the selected value of the ng2-select

Tags: select, angular, multi-select

I am working on angular2 application, I have use the ng2-select for the multiselect dropdown. Its working fine while creating new entry. But when trying to implement same while **editing**  I am not able to set the default selected **values pulled form database**.

```
  <ng-select [initData]="aminities" (data)="refreshValue($event)" [multiple]="true" [items]="items" [disabled]="disabled"></ng-select>


export class EditProjectComponent {
    project: ProjectModel;
    routeParam: RouteParams;
    aminities: any;
    private items: Array<string> = ['Swimming Pool', 'Gymnasium', 'Lift', 'Power Backup',
        'Landscaped Garden', 'Security', 'Community Hall', 'Jogging Track', 'Childrens Play Area'];
    constructor(
        @Inject(Router) private router: Router,
        @Inject(ProjectService) private projectService: ProjectService,
        routeParam: RouteParams,
        private _formBuilder: FormBuilder
    ) {

        this.project = new ProjectModel();
        this.routeParam = routeParam;
        if (this.routeParam.params['id'] != undefined) {
            this.projectService.getbyId(this.routeParam.params['id'], (res) => {
                this.project = res;
                this.aminities = this.project.overview.aminities;

            }, () => { });
        }
    }

  }
```

After response came i have to set the **aminities** values in ng2-select.

Please correct me how to set the default selected values.

Comment: can't you generate new select again with selected value and initialize ng2 select again ?

Comment: I didn't quite get your question. Are you trying to change the items on your select ? Or are you trying so select a value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to select all the `aminities` after they come back from the response you can trigger it by pushing them to `active`.

This is the only way I found to do it. There's certainly a better option.

First we add the select as view children.

```
import {Select} from 'your-location';

export class EditProjectComponent {
    //...

    @ViewChild(Select)
    private select: Select;

    //...
}
```

(If you have more then 1 then use `@viewChildren` and `QueryList<>`)

After that, we first find the options that are selected from the `itemObjects`.

```
let arr = [];
arr = this.select.itemObjects.filter((x) => {
   let isAminities = this.aminities.find((y) => y.text === x.text);
   return (isAminities !== -1) ? true: false;
})
```

Now that we have `arr` with all the items we need we just push it to the select active list.

```
this.select.active.push(arr)
```

The end result:

```
export class EditProjectComponent {
    project: ProjectModel;
    routeParam: RouteParams;
    aminities: any;

    @ViewChild(Select)
    private select: Select;

    private items: Array<string> = ['Swimming Pool', 'Gymnasium', 'Lift', 'Power Backup',
        'Landscaped Garden', 'Security', 'Community Hall', 'Jogging Track', 'Childrens Play Area'];
    constructor(
        @Inject(Router) private router: Router,
        @Inject(ProjectService) private projectService: ProjectService,
        routeParam: RouteParams,
        private _formBuilder: FormBuilder
    ) {

        this.project = new ProjectModel();
        this.routeParam = routeParam;
        if (this.routeParam.params['id'] != undefined) {
            this.projectService.getbyId(this.routeParam.params['id'], (res) => {
                this.project = res;
                this.aminities = this.project.overview.aminities;
                let arr = [];
                arr = this.select.itemObjects.filter((x) => {
                   let isAminities = this.aminities.find((y) => y === x.text);
                   return (isAminities !== -1) ? true: false;
                })
                this.select.active.push(arr)

            }, () => { });
        }
    }

  }
```

I know there will be other options to do this. But so far that's the only one I was able to work with.

Comment: this.project.overview.aminities is just the array of string

Comment: then on find just do: `y === x.text`

Comment: @JoelAlmeida will u explain what is your-location in import {SELECT} from 'your-location';? I tried import {SELECT} from 'ng2-select/ng2-select' where i am getting my SELECT_DIRECTIVES but getting error.

Comment: @DarshanPuranik it should be `Select`, not `SELECT`. sorry.

Comment: @JoelAlmeida i am not able to get Select in import statement. I cant seem to find select mofule.

Comment: import {SELECT_DIRECTIVES, SelectComponent} from 'ng2-select'; // assuming you have installed ng2-select with npm --save-dev