# How to set the option of the ng2-select which is coming from responce

Tags: select, angular

I am working on angular2 application, I have use the ng2-select for the dropdown. Its working fine when i hard-code the list of option. But my requirement is to pull the list form the server and then list in select.

```
export class EditProjectComponent {
     routeParam: RouteParams;
     aminities: any;
    @ViewChild(Select)
    private select: Select;

    private items: Array<string> = [''];
    constructor(
        @Inject(Router) private router: Router,
        @Inject(ProjectService) private projectService: ProjectService,
        @Inject(DeveloperService) private developerService: DeveloperService,
        @Inject(AmenityService) private amenityService: AmenityService,
        routeParam: RouteParams,
        private _formBuilder: FormBuilder
    ) {

        this.project = new ProjectModel();
        this.routeParam = routeParam;
        this.getAmenities();
    }

      private getAmenities() {
        this.items.length = 0;
        this.amenityService.get((res) => {
            res.forEach(element => {
                this.items.push(element.name);
            });
        }, (err) => { })
    }
}
```

Html:

```
  <ng-select [initData]="aminities" (data)="refreshValue($event)" [multiple]="true" [items]="items" [disabled]="disabled"></ng-select>
```

I am getting error

**Cannot read property 'hasChildren' of undefined in [disabled in EditProjectComponent@148:114]**

Comment: What position is `@148:114`?

Comment: dont know my EditProjectComponent just have 116 line only after compile it has 135 line

Comment: The only difference between this question and this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35551444/how-to-set-the-selected-value-of-the-ng2-select/35556107#35556107 is that your items need to come from the server. right? or that answer didnt work?

Comment: yes, item need to come form server

Comment: ng-select will get initialize before the response come back

Comment: remove the `[initData]="aminities"` and let me know what happens

Comment: No its not making any difference

Comment: @Rhushikesh Did you find the answer for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private getAmenities() {
        this.items.length = 0;
        this.amenityService.get((res) => {
            res.forEach(element => {
                this.items.push(element.name);
                this.select.itemObjects.push(new SelectItem({ id: element._id, text: element.name }));
            });
        }, (err) => { })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Current version docs explained better:   [ng2-select / valor-software.com](https://valor-software.com/ng2-select/)

**View side (*category-edit.component.html*):**

```
<ng-select [multiple]="true" [items]="tags" [active]="active_tags"></ng-select>
```

No matter if there is one or more elements, always must contain Array format, *Ex.: [{id: 1, text: MyText}] or [{id: 1, text: MyText1}, {id: 2, text: MyText2}]*

**Component side (*category-edit.component.ts*):**

```
import {Component, OnInit, Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

   getTagsByCategoryId(id: string): Observable<any> { /** callback */}
}

export interface SelectOption{
   id?: string;
   text?: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-category-edit',
  templateUrl: 'category-edit.component.html'     
});

export class CategoriesComponent extends OnInit{
   tags: SelectOption[]; /** Assumed you already loaded these */ 
   active_tags: SelectOption[];     

 constructor(private myService:MyService){
   super();
 }
 ngOnInit(){
   this.init();
 }

 init(){

   const id= "the_id"; /** Some valid id to query */
   /** Callback */
   this.myService
       .getTagsByCategoryId(id)(
          response=> {
            if(response.error){ console.error(response.error);}   
            }else{
               console.log(response.result;)
               this.active_tags= <SelectOption[]> response.result;
            }  
          },
          error => {console.error(error);}
     );
 }
```

}